# PyCharm terminal doesn't recognize Python or Pip

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm for a project, and I've been having a problem I can't understand. In the "terminal" (in PyCharm), I activate the virtualenv I want, which has Python and all my other packages. The project works, which means the packages are being found, because otherwise it wouldn't work. But the thing is, neither python nor pip are recognized in the PyCharm terminal. This happens whether the virtualenv is activated or deactivated, so I don't think that's the issue.

I get the "python is not a recognized internal or external command" message, but if I do it in the file system, for instance, I can use python, pip, and everything else just fine, so I think it might be a configuration of my PyCharm, most likely, but I don't even know where to look, I don't see anything in the settings that I find odd. Any help could save me a lot of time I've been stuck with this. I'm on Windows 10, by the way.

The environment variable 'PATH' is 'C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36', and python is recognized anywhere but within the PyCharm terminal.

Comment: Are you sure that `ls` command is not working? What is the `OS` that you are working on?

Comment: I'm on windows 10, I was mistaken about that, a friend told me to try, and then I remembered I'm on windows, I'll update the question. "cd" command does work, for example.

Comment: Are you sure that your environment variable `PATH` contain the directory for the `python` executable?

Comment: I'll update the question with that info, @SukumarRdjf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows.

You have to add paths to python & pip in environment variables. If you have no previous experience doing so. I would ask to use this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrhkbjDAUV0.

If I am getting your problem wrong sorry.

Comment: Well, I do have the paths to python set, I think I would get the "python is not recognized" message everywhere, no? And I only get that in the PyCharm terminal, in my file system the command does work. And since I'm using Django, I need to use the PyCharm terminal with the virtualenv to run the command there; the project works, but I need to make migrations with the django "python manage.py makemigrations" command, but I can't at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with you, I use Poetry for virtual env management, but I can't use poetry command in Pycharm terminal.
I notice that if I open Pycharm as Administrator then it works fine.

Comment: Your response does not answer the question at all. If you do cannot provide answer (for instance, because you ran into the same problem and could not resolve it), it is ok to leave it unanswered.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35076752)